# Ext JS extreame start

Tags: javascript, extjs

Собственно сабж, нужно ознакомиться с технологией, времени в обрез, с английским проблем не имею. Приветствуются любые ссылки, книги, семинары, размышления ресурсы и т.д. и т.п.

Примечание - не надо писать типа - в маны, в доку и т.д. Туда идут тогда когда решают конкретную задачу (скорее даже подзадачу), мне же нужно очень быстрое комплексное изучение фреймворка в целом.

PS: я мог бы и сам погуглить и что-то да найти и как-то да учить, но практика показывает что это лишнее время, которого, к сожалению, у меня сейчас нет, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Оффтоп:

Проработал с ним год... Из аналогов которые видел - самый простой... Организация "классов" - ужасное месево...

Comment: Я тоже не рад этому, ИМХО для большинства задач достаточно jquery, prototype ( более того все что есть в ext можно написать самому при необходимости ), но во первых самому хочется попробовать ибо чем больше знаешь тем лучше да и фреймворк связан с так мною любимым языком =)

Но основная причина - нужно по работе, исключительно для расширения кругозора я бы, естественно, выбрал бы что-то другое.

В любом случае - спс за предупреждение по поводу "классов" :D

Comment: Про ExtJS я сказал со стороны RIA, где тот-же jQuery - **слишком** низкоуровневый что-бы как-то помочь, за что и не питаю к нему тёплых чувств.

Comment: @timka_s - высоко-философские рассуждения это, несомненно, чудесно, но тем не менее - по теме у вас ничего нет?..

Comment: В принципе там всего-то 4 страницы по ext, так что, скорее всего - не так уж глубоко, спасибо

Comment: Хочу еще немного оффтопа =)
@timka_s - как часто используете в реальной разработке?

Comment: 2 больших проекта на нём было... Теперь свой пишу ( блекджек и etc )

Comment: Какая версия интересует? ExtJS 3 и ExtJS 4 существенно различаются.

Comment: Четвертая версия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ради интереса читал http://mytrouble.ru/category/extjs.

В принципе, примеры с оф. сайта... На оф. сайте где-то ооочень глубоко спрятан прикольный туториал...

Comment: Отрыл кстати, причем довольно быстро =)